# How do I use faker.js to pick a random enum value?

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums, faker.js

Given an enumeration such as:

```
enum DistributionType {
    Calculated = "Calculated",
    Custom = "Custom",
    None = "None",
}
```

How do I use Faker.JS to pick a random enum value from it?

```
const randomValue = faker.???
```

Reference:
https://fakerjs.dev/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For @faker-js/faker > 8.0.0 you can now also use the following helper:

```
const randomValue = faker.helpers.enumValue(DistributionType);
```

Answer (score 15):

I ended up doing this, as I didn't see any specific helpers for enums.

```
const randomValue = faker.helpers.arrayElement(Object.values(DistributionType));
```